# Install composer in Windows server without internet access

Tags: composer-php

I was trying to install Composer in a windows server, where there was obsoletely no possibility to get internet access due to permission issues. I was unable to do it. So please do suggest any ways to that possible.

Comment: You can manually download composer.phar and transfer it to the server, assuming you have some way to do that. Check the "Manual Download" section in the composer documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Composer itself (which needs internet access to install packages) on a system without internet access? What would be the use case for this?

Comment: @NicoHaase: You can run composer for a project with no dependencies, e.g. to make use of the autoloader. Fair enough it is limited, but also only the start: You can then add local repositories and use them. There is even an offline flag.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading the file `composer.phar` you need to find a different way to transfer it to the computer in question.

Next to the file `composer.phar` that computer needs to provide the PHP executable (with a couple of extensions: phar, iconv and json). Recommended is as well the zip extension. Additionally the system should provide at least the unzip and 7z utilities, I'd also recommend the git utility.

Offline systems are often managed. Contact your manager on how to obtain information with whom you need to talk to discuss on how to transfer files to that system and who is responsible for that and which steps are required to do so (review process, deployments etc.).

- Composers Homepage is: https://getcomposer.org/
- PHPs Homepage is: https://php.net/

Comment: Much Thanks! I am now trying to get the composer.phar through the repository and try installing in an internet less environment.